# Не получается распределить права на папки и файлы

Tags: linux, сервер, права, vsftpd

Есть сервер, там есть `ftp аккаунт`(webuser). Используем `vsftpd`.. подключается через `filezilla`, создаем файл\папку, а там автоматом вешаются права `-rw-------`

Как это исправить? Чтобы автоматически, при создании папкам присваивались права `755`, а файлам - `644` ?

Спасибо!

Comment: Где-то в конфиге `vsftpd`, скорее всего что-то про `umask`

Comment: вы совершенно правы! но вот еще,как мне сделать так, чтобы "при создании папкам присваивались права 755, а файлам - 644 "? выставил umask = 022.. и к папкам и к файлам присваиваются одинаковые права - 755

Comment: Возможно `vsftpd` умеет в разные `umask` для файлов и директорий. Помнится в `proftpd` что-то такое было, а может вру, давно это было.

Comment: Когда разберётесь с проблемой, не поленитесь написать ответ, что-бы другие могли им воспользоваться

Comment: все, разобрался, закомментировал строку `file_open_mode` и все заработало! Спасибо! Перенесите ваш комментарий в ответ, чтобы я мог подтвердить его

Comment: Лучше вы сами обстоятельно напишите что там к чему, будет вам плюс в карму, а ресурсу качественный ответ. Я конфиг `vsftpd` видел один раз лет пять назад, ничего кроме общих слов про `umask` сказать про него не могу.